# Inner product that snipes out the zero element

Tags: vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

Say I have a complex Hilbert space, with the typical inner product:

$$
\langle u,v \rangle=u^\dagger v
$$

The inner product for the zero element is also zero : $\langle 0,0 \rangle=0$

Say, I am to call the zero state an 'undesirable' state (it produces non-normalizable states for a wave-function, for instance). Can I remove it from the inner product? Can I define the inner product as follows:

$$
\langle u,v \rangle=\begin{cases}  \nexists & \text{if } u=v=0 \\ u^\dagger v & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}
$$

Quantum Mechanics seems to like it --- this is basically the inner product of allowed physical states. Is there any reason mathematicians don't like that? Is the space still a Hilbert space. If not what is it?

Comment: It's no longer an inner product, so the space is definitely not Hilbert with respect to the "inner product" you've defined.

Comment: @Stuck  The fourth axiom of the inner product states that if $<u,u>=0$ then $u=0$. As it is written, it does not seem to require the zero element to be defined. Maybe I am missing something?

Comment: It's a thing like a Hilbert space, except that you've decided that you don't like the zero vector having a norm.

Comment: @Gae.S. Precisely. If the universe doesn't like it (quantum states must be normalizable), then neither do I.

Comment: @Anon21 It follows from bilinearity that the inner product of a zero vector with any other vector is zero: $\langle0,y \rangle=\langle0x,y \rangle=0\langle x,y \rangle =0$

Comment: If you take away the origin, then it's not a Hilbert space. Quantum states live in the unit sphere of a Hilbert space. Or is it projective Hilbert space? I never quite could nail down which one it was meant to be. Some times it felt like QM flip-flops between the two as it sees fit.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can define it this way.  In mathematics, we may define anything whichever way we like.  The question you should be asking is: *does this definition make anything I'm doing easier?*

We do not need ontological commitment to the entities of our models, and there's really no reason to try to "pare down" a model to only entities that seem "real," unless you can do it in a way that systematically avoids the need to manually handle edge-cases.

As far as I can tell, this does the opposite of that.  It doesn't systematically change anything; all it does is introduce the need to propagate a bunch of extra conditions through all of the proofs.  Anyone using the mathematics to actually *describe* a thing will be able to prune the nonphysical entities post-hoc - there's no need to tediously carry the caveats through each step of the math when they don't change the logical structure of the arguments.